# How to verify dynamic gallery with Selenium WebDriver using Java?

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver

**Problem:**

The image in the gallery is always dynamic, but the article keeps changing. When I click on the article the image gallery open with a big image and other thumbnails with a carousel.

---

**First Scenario :**

I need to verify that the image is loaded and the gallery is fine. Also the other thumbnail images has to be navigated and verified.`

**Example:**

- 1. I am on a article page and i open that article, so this article page has an Gallery opened with > 5 thumbnails images.
- 2. Now I need to verify that the image is opened and also navigate one after the another to verify the thumbnails as well.

---

**2nd Scenario :**

Is some times this article will have image loaded ,were has sometimes it can have video's or just a single image. So that's what i meant to be it as Dynamic.`

So each time the image change,need to know how to handle this situation 
Below is the html code:

```
<div class="carousel royalSlider rsDefault rsAutoHeight rsHor  rsWithThumbs rsWithThumbsHor" style="min-height: 463.8px;">
    <div class="rsOverflow" style="width: 773px; height: 436px; transition:  height 600ms ease-in-out;">
        <div class="rsContainer" style="transition-duration: 600ms; transform:  translate3d(-797px, 0px, 0px); transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.445,  0.05, 0.55, 0.95);">
            <div style="left: 0px;" class="rsSlide"><img class="rsImg  rsMainSlideImage"  src="http://resources.carsguide.com.au/styles/cg_hero_large/s3/lexus-rx350-2016- (1).jpg"></div>
            <div style="left: 797px;" class="rsSlide rsActiveSlide"><img  class="rsImg rsMainSlideImage"  src="http://resources.carsguide.com.au/styles/cg_hero_large/s3/lexus-rx350-2016- (2).jpg"></div>
            <div style="left: 1594px;" class="rsSlide "><img class="rsImg  rsMainSlideImage"  src="http://resources.carsguide.com.au/styles/cg_hero_large/s3/lexus-rx350-2016- (3).jpg"></div>
            <div style="left: 2391px;" class="rsSlide "><img class="rsImg  rsMainSlideImage"  src="http://resources.carsguide.com.au/styles/cg_hero_large/s3/lexus-rx350-2016- (4).jpg"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="rsFullscreenBtn">
            <div class="rsFullscreenIcn"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="rsArrow rsArrowLeft" style="display: block;">
            <div class="rsArrowIcn"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="rsArrow rsArrowRight" style="display: block;">
            <div class="rsArrowIcn"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="rsGCaption">Lexus RX 350 F Sport.<noscript>&lt;img  src=http://resources.carsguide.com.au/styles/cg_hero_thumbnail/s3/lexus-rx350- 2016-(2).jpg&gt;</noscript></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rsNav rsThumbs rsThumbsHor">
        <div class="rsThumbsContainer" style="transition-property: -webkit- transform; transform: translate3d(86.5px, 0px, 0px); width: 612px;">
            <div style="margin-right:12px;" class="rsNavItem rsThumb"><img  class="rsTmb lazyload" onerror="this.style.visibility='hidden'" data- src="http://resources.carsguide.com.au/styles/cg_hero_thumbnail/s3/lexus-rx350- 2016-(1).jpg"  src="http://resources.carsguide.com.au/styles/cg_hero_thumbnail/s3/lexus-rx350- 2016-(1).jpg" width="90" height="50" alt=""><span class="thumbIco"></span></div>
            <div style="margin-right:12px;" class="rsNavItem rsThumb  rsNavSelected"><img class="rsTmb lazyload"  onerror="this.style.visibility='hidden'" data- src="http://resources.carsguide.com.au/styles/cg_hero_thumbnail/s3/lexus-rx350- 2016-(2).jpg"  src="http://resources.carsguide.com.au/styles/cg_hero_thumbnail/s3/lexus-rx350- 2016-(2).jpg" width="90" height="50" alt=""><span class="thumbIco"></span></div>
            <div style="margin-right:12px;" class="rsNavItem rsThumb"><img c lass="rsTmb lazyload" onerror="this.style.visibility='hidden'" data- src="http://resources.carsguide.com.au/styles/cg_hero_thumbnail/s3/lexus-rx350- 2016-(3).jpg"  src="http://resources.carsguide.com.au/styles/cg_hero_thumbnail/s3/lexus-rx350- 2016-(3).jpg" width="90" height="50" alt=""><span class="thumbIco"></span></div>
            <div style="margin-right:12px;" class="rsNavItem rsThumb"><img  class="rsTmb lazyload" onerror="this.style.visibility='hidden'" data- src="http://resources.carsguide.com.au/styles/cg_hero_thumbnail/s3/lexus-rx350- 2016-(4).jpg"  src="http://resources.carsguide.com.au/styles/cg_hero_thumbnail/s3/lexus-rx350- 2016-(4).jpg" width="90" height="50" alt=""><span class="thumbIco"></span></div>
            <div style="margin-right:12px;" class="rsNavItem rsThumb"><img  class="rsTmb lazyload" onerror="this.style.visibility='hidden'" data- src="http://resources.carsguide.com.au/styles/cg_hero_thumbnail/s3/lexus-rx350- 2016-(5).jpg"  src="http://resources.carsguide.com.au/styles/cg_hero_thumbnail/s3/lexus-rx350- 2016-(5).jpg" width="90" height="50" alt=""><span class="thumbIco"></span></div>
            <div style="margin-right:12px;" class="rsNavItem rsThumb"><img  class="rsTmb lazyload" onerror="this.style.visibility='hidden'" data- src="http://resources.carsguide.com.au/styles/cg_hero_thumbnail/s3/lexus-rx350- 2016-(6).jpg"  src="http://resources.carsguide.com.au/styles/cg_hero_thumbnail/s3/lexus-rx350- 2016-(6).jpg" width="90" height="50" alt=""><span class="thumbIco"></span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="rsThumbsArrow rsThumbsArrowLeft  rsThumbsArrowDisabled">
            <div class="rsThumbsArrowIcn"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="rsThumbsArrow rsThumbsArrowRight rsThumbsArrowDisabled">
            <div class="rsThumbsArrowIcn"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both; float: none;"></div>
</div>
```

All I have done so far is :

- 1. Open the URL.
- 2. Click on the Article page.
- 3. Now open that / any article.

My 4th step would be to verify that image (with thumbnails) when the article opens. I am not able to do that 4th step. I don't have any error now, I am able to do it successfully till step 3.

Comment: what do you mean by dynamic gallery please be more specific

Comment: @rajNishKuMar ex: I am on a article page and i open that article, so this article page has an Gallary opened with > 5 thumbnails images. Now i need to verify that the image is opened and also navigate one after the another to verify the thumbnails as well. The 2nd Scenario is some times this article will have image loaded ,were has sometimes it can have video;s or just a single image. So thats what i meant to be it as Dynamic

Comment: ok in that case the problem you are facing is that how to tell which time image is there and which time video is there

Comment: All i have done so far is 1. Open the URL 2. Click on the Article page 3. Now open that / any article. My 4th step would be to verify that image (with thumbnails) when the article opens. I am not able to do that 4th step. I dont have any error now, i am able to do it successfully till step3. Here is the example of the website: http://www.carsguide.com.au/car-reviews/2016-lexus-rx350-review-road-test-41986

Comment: Thanks, Will try out and let you know.,How did it go

Comment: @rajNishKuMar It worked,thanks a ton. Look forward to your help for any more complicated issues

Comment: yeah sure i am glad that it helped

Comment: @rajNishKuMar can you help me on this again, the other day it was working. Now there is an issue, the script gets stopped before the last thumbnail and it basically ends like this : Url for the Thumbnail is : http://resources.carsguide.com.au/styles/cg_hero_thumbnail/s3/volkswagen-amarok-2016-(6).jpg ......Url for the main image is : http://resources.carsguide.com.au/styles/cg_hero_large/s3/volkswagen-amarok-2016-(4).jpg which is incorrect. Did try to debug but its not working

Comment: Hi i have gone through the code as provided by me and its working correctly.

Comment: @rajNishKuMar http://www.carsguide.com.au/car-reviews/audi-q7-tdi-160-2016-review-road-test-42212 for this link its not working, basically any link with more than 3 thumbnails its not workig..tried to debug but not finding solu...please let me know your thoughts

Comment: It fails after 3 or 4th thumbnails verification, basically it tries to compare the current thumbnails with the next one which its not even clicking to go there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi please do it like below

```
public class WorkingWithThumbNails {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://www.carsguide.com.au/car-reviews/toyota-tarago-used-review-1990-2015-41984");

    // Now count the number of images in the thumb-nails cause
    // this will decide number of clicks on the next Arrow

    List<WebElement> myThumbnails = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".rsTmb.lazyload"));
    List<WebElement> myMainImages = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".rsImg.rsMainSlideImage"));

    System.out.println("Size of the thumbnail is : " + myThumbnails.size());
    System.out.println("Size of the main image is : " + myMainImages.size());


    // print the urls of the thumb-nails as well
    for(int i=0;i< myThumbnails.size();i++){
        myThumbnails = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".rsTmb.lazyload"));
        System.out.println("Url for the Thumbnail is : " + myThumbnails.get(i).getAttribute("src"));

        myMainImages = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".rsImg.rsMainSlideImage"));
        System.out.println("Url for the main image is : " + myMainImages.get(i).getAttribute("src"));

        // now implement the logic of img verification, logic can be many but here i used if src for bigger img 
        // contains img name as per the thumbnail img name then its ok img is properly loaded and hence it is right image.

        String[] myMainImgName = myMainImages.get(i).getAttribute("src").split("s3");

        if(myThumbnails.get(i).getAttribute("src").contains(myMainImgName[1])){
            System.out.println("Main image is as per the thumbnail.");
            // to verify next thumb-nail img with main img we have to click
            // here if is because loop will run one more time then img size
            if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='rsArrow rsArrowRight']/div")).size() > 0){
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='rsArrow rsArrowRight']/div")).click();
            }
        }else{
            // apply the same logic for videos 
            // hope you can do this 
        }
    }

}
```

}

Please feel free to ask query if any.